# Problem with recursive deletion of folders with Delphi

Tags: delphi, delete-file, delete-directory

I have the following routine, which I found on the internet, to delete to the `recycle bin` some folders that contain files and other folders. It works fine unless there is a `zip file`. Then it gives me the error 120 (= this function is not supported), even if I change the extension from `zip` to eg `bck`. I guess the function sees the zip file as a folder but it can't handle it and throws an error.
Does anyone know how I can overcome this problem?

```
function recycleFile(fileName: string): boolean;
var
    fos: TSHFileOpStruct;
    erNo : integer;
begin
    setlength(fileName, length(fileName) + 1);
    fileName[length(fileName)] := #0;
    FillChar(fos, SizeOf(fos), 0);
    with fos do
    begin
        wFunc := FO_DELETE;
        pFrom := PChar(fileName);
        fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_NOERRORUI;
    end;
    erNo := ShFileOperation(fos);
    if erNo <> 0 then showmessage(intToStr(erNo));

    result := erNo = 0;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

This code works for me (using Delphi 12, on Windows 11):

```
function DeleteDirectory(const ADirectory: string): Boolean;
var
  LShFileOp: TSHFileOpStruct;
begin
  FillChar(LShFileOp, SizeOf(LShFileOp), 0);
  LShFileOp.wFunc := FO_DELETE;
  LShFileOp.pFrom := PChar(ADirectory + #0);
  LShFileOp.pTo := nil;
  LShFileOp.fFlags := FOF_ALLOWUNDO or FOF_NOCONFIRMATION or FOF_SILENT;
  Result := SHFileOperation(LShFileOp) = 0;
end;
```

It can include folders that contain .zip files.

Comment: But not when deleting to recycle bin with flag FOF_ALLOWUNDO !  it asks for administrator rights (when move FOF_NO_UI flag)

Comment: still can't delete folder with zip files in recycle bin

Comment: What do you mean by "can't delete folder with zip files in recycle bin"? The code is not for deleting folders from the recycle bin, it's for sending them there (including .zip files). If that fails, what result code are you receiving? If it's 120, your process does not have permissions to delete

Comment: No, i want to sent folders to recycle bin, but when they include zip files throws the error 120 that means I haven't rights for this operation, even when I run the app as administrator. But I can delete the same folder with windows file explorer without asking for rights.

Comment: OK, well the amended code works for me - perhaps you need to check permissions on the folders you're recycling

Comment: The folder has files and a subfolder that has a zip file. Trying to recycle it by code I receive the error 120. I recycle the zip file with file explorer so the subfolder has not any zip files and trying to recycle the parent folder succeeds! Restoring from recycle bin the folder and the zip file again fails! the rights for zip file are exactly the same as all other files in folder (modify,read,execute,write). I'm using windows 11/64b